# Bliss automorphisms - how to list all automorphisms using the output generators?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am using the program called Bliss to try to extract all automorphisms of an input graph.  The software itself does not list all of the automorphisms directly but instead outputs a list of "generators" that are mappings to get at least one automorphism per generator.

What I'm stuck on is that I don't see a clear pattern of how to list ALL automorphisms using the generators.  Bliss may output two generators, but the total number of automorphisms could be 4 (which includes the identity mapping).

Example Graph:
[image]
Source: Page 24 [http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4203/files/GT-Lec2.pdf](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ecs4203/files/GT-Lec2.pdf)

Bliss Output:

```
Graph read in 0.00 seconds
Initial partition computed in 0.00 seconds
Generator: (1,8)(2,7)
Level 1: orbits=6, index=2/2, all_same_level=1
Generator: (3,5)(4,6)
Level 0: orbits=4, index=2/2, all_same_level=0
Nodes:          5
Leaf nodes:     3
Bad nodes:      0
Canrep updates: 1
Generators:     2
Max level:      2
|Aut|:          4
Total time: 0.00 seconds
```

The output says |Aut| = 4, which is correct since there are 4 automorphisms per the example screenshot.

The output has the generators that correspond to two of the automorphisms from the example.  Another automorphism is the identity.  But what I don't know how to get from these generators is the last automorphism shown in the screenshot using the generators.  Also, I'm looking for a general method to list all automorphisms, not only for this example too.  If anyone has any insight on this or even alternative tools that could do the task, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. This is a stack site about the technical computing software called Mathematica and the associated Wolfram Language. At this point your question is off-topic. If you are looking for a `general method to list all automorphisms`, you can ask at the [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: thanks Syed, I'll also ask there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in function `GroupElements` in *Mathematica* to get all the elements in a group generated by a set of generators.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 4, 5 <-> 6, 
   7 <-> 8, 3 <-> 7, 5 <-> 7}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
gr = GraphAutomorphismGroup[g]
GroupElements[gr]
```

[image]

```
Out1: PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 8}, {2, 7}}], Cycles[{{3, 4}, {5, 6}}]}]
Out2: {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{3, 4}, {5, 6}}], Cycles[{{1, 8}, {2, 7}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 8}, {2, 7}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]}
```

**Edits:** If only the set of edges is input to the `Graph` function, it seems to affect the accuracy of the result, and I haven't figured out the specific reason yet. But if I process it as follows, there will be no problem.

```
g = Graph[
  Range[8], {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 5, 3 <-> 4, 5 <-> 6, 
   7 <-> 8, 3 <-> 7, 5 <-> 7}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
gr = GraphAutomorphismGroup[g]
GroupElements[gr]
```

```
Out1: PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 8}, {2, 7}}], Cycles[{{3, 5}, {4, 6}}]}]
Out2: {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{3, 5}, {4, 6}}], Cycles[{{1, 8}, {2, 7}}], 
 Cycles[{{1, 8}, {2, 7}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}]}
```

Comment: For the graph `g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 5, 5 <-> 6, 
   3 <-> 7, 5 <-> 7, 7 <-> 8}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]` , it is Ok.

Comment: I feel that the generator (Cycles[{{3, 4}, {5, 6}}]) is strange . I'm not sure if the internal vertex labels have been adjusted.

Comment: thanks licheng!  Good catch on the output, it may be a labels issue in the backend.  Looks like I have a couple of options here, I can either switch to Mathematica or find out how "GroupElements" works since it appears that is the functionality I'm ultimately looking to achieve.  If you have any insight on that please let me know, I'm reviewing this page https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupElements.html